# Flexbox vertical alignment issue on input tag

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, flexbox

Basically, I have a `label` and a text `input` inline with one another in a flexbox, with the `input` flexing, `align-items` set to baseline. The `input` flexes to fill out the containing `div` properly, but the `label` aligns with the bottom of the `input` instead of where the text baseline should be.

This problem presents itself in Chrome, and possibly other WebKit browsers.

Here's the code. [You can check out how it renders in this Codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/olhvK)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type='text' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  width:20rem;
  background:#999;
  padding:.5rem;

  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}

input{
  flex:1;
}
```

If you comment out `display: flex`, the alignment is correct, but naturally it's no longer flexing.

How can I fix this without using a hack like `align-items: center`?

Note: I originally posted this question and answer in a different question and it was deleted. I've revised it as suggested and hopefully it meets the guidelines now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, without the presence of a `value` or `placeholder` attribute on the `input`, the layout engine interprets the baseline of the `input` as the bottom of the `input`, not where the text baseline should be.

So the modified HTML would look like:

```
<div>
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type='text' value='example@gmail.com' />
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type='text' placeholder='example@gmail.com' />
</div>
```

This is a bug with the layout engine, and the devs have been notified. [You can read more about the bug here.](http://courtdemone.tumblr.com/post/70222022496/flexbox-alignment-bug-on-input-tags)

Comment: this still seems to be bugged, do you have a link to where you raised the issue?

Comment: @slicedtoad I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You said you notified the devs, I assumed that meant you posted the bug somewhere like this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list or the google chrome product forums. I suppose you could have just used the 'report an issue' button though

Comment: @slicedtoad That's a good question! I'm not sure where I brought it up. It's likely that their have been other bugs taking priority for them. I suppose you could bring it up to them again!

Comment: Here is the issue in the tracker: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401185

Comment: It's worth noting that this might not even be a bug, but correct behavior, due to the exception stated at the end of https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading

Answer (score 2):

Add to the other answers, `<input type="text" placeholder=" ">` works great if you don't want to actually show any placeholding text.

Comment: Is there some way to apply an empty placeholder text to all text input fields using a CSS selector?

Comment: Adding a placeholder using jQuery doesn't appear to work: https://jsfiddle.net/wkrick/mheke9b9/

Comment: It doesn't work to fix the alignment issue in Chrome.  I've added a red box to illustrate the misalignment that is still there after running your jsfiddle...  http://imgur.com/a/lej2g